# What is the generic word for a TV broadcast?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What word should I use to translate Russian word "телепередача"?

I mean a distinct interval in TV broadcast dedicated to a certain topic and united with the same format such as a talk show, newsreel, an analytic monologue/dialogue, a learning TV class etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be a **programme**. However Google translate gives **telecast**, which I am not sure fits your description.

Comment: Google Translate gives *broadcast, TV program, TV show* and *television program* as alternate translations.

Comment: In non-UK English (i.e. everywhere else), it should be "program".

Comment: @Translator1983: No, in India we use programme for TV shows and program for software codes.

Comment: I won't argue with that, but I wish to point out that the English spoken in India comes from British English. I should have mentioned that "programme" is also used in many former English colonies.